# Links in snippets

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, hyperlinks

I have a [post on a multi-search-bar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/171391/9357) that just recently got marked as on-hold for broken code. I looked through it and it's considered broken code because I can't link to websites.

I have two questions:

1. Can you allow links in snippets?
2. Can my post be reopened?

Answer (score 8):

No, that is not the reason for the closure. Your question was closed because the code doesn't work.

> ```
> function google() {
>   var good = document.getElementById("theStuff");
>   window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + good;
> }
> ```

Concatenating a string with a DOM element makes no sense.